# How to create buttons in a for loop without losing their references?

Tags: javascript, dom, button, reference

I am trying to create buttons for each letter in alphabet. When the button is pressed, it will alert the letter written on the button. But i think since i create them i a for loop, js can't keep their reference because when i open the browser, on the each button 'undefined' is written. I also tried to add the buttons to an array then append them to the container, but the result was same. Is there any way to fix this problem? Thanks.

```
function CreateButtons()
{
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPRSTUVYZQWXI";
    var frame = document.getElementById('buttons'); //container. 
   
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length;i++)
    {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.type = 'button';
            button.innerHTML = letters[i];
            button.className = 'btn-styled';
            button.style.padding = "20px";
            button.style.marginTop = "10px";
            button.style.lineHeight = "30px";
            button.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            button.style.padding = "0 30px";
            button.style.background = "salmon";
            button.style.border = "none";
            button.style.color ="blue";

            button.onclick = function() {
              alert(letters[i]); //when the button is pressed, it will alert the letter at i. position.
            };
            frame.appendChild(button);
          }, false);
         
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a closure. Because loop will finish its execution and the button created will never know the value of `letter[i]`

```js
function CreateButtons() {
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPRSTUVYZQWXI";
  var frame = document.getElementById('buttons'); //container. 

  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    (function(z) {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.type = 'button';
        button.innerHTML = z;
        button.className = 'btn-styled';
        button.style.padding = "20px";
        button.style.marginTop = "10px";
        button.style.lineHeight = "30px";
        button.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        button.style.padding = "0 30px";
        button.style.background = "salmon";
        button.style.border = "none";
        button.style.color = "blue";

        button.onclick = function() {
          alert(z); //when the button is pressed, it will alert the letter at i. position.
        };
        frame.appendChild(button);
      }, false);
    }(letters[i]))


  }
}
CreateButtons()
```

```html
<div id='buttons'></div>
```

Alternatively instead of `var` use `let`

```js
function CreateButtons() {
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPRSTUVYZQWXI";
  var frame = document.getElementById('buttons'); //container. 

  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.type = 'button';
      button.innerHTML = letters[i];
      button.className = 'btn-styled';
      button.style.padding = "20px";
      button.style.marginTop = "10px";
      button.style.lineHeight = "30px";
      button.style.fontWeight = "bold";
      button.style.padding = "0 30px";
      button.style.background = "salmon";
      button.style.border = "none";
      button.style.color = "blue";

      button.onclick = function() {
        alert(letters[i]); //when the button is pressed, it will alert the letter at i. position.
      };
      frame.appendChild(button);
    }, false);
 }
}
CreateButtons()
```

```html
<div id='buttons'></div>
```

Comment: I updated my code many times to fix this. But the problem was very simple to notice.

Comment: My `letters` var is an `async/await` call to an api that awaits a result. The result ist then looped and buttons are added to each res elem with a listener. It works without the `domcontentloader` listener so probably not needed when there is an await call involved.